# Java FXML java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set

Tags: java, fxmlloader, openjfx

I'm trying to create application using FXML file for my window, but I can't get this to work, none of answers on StackOverflow worked for me and I'M stuck.

Class where I want to load file

```
public FXMLWindow() {
        final FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("/test.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
    try {
        fxmlLoader.load();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
}
```

FXML file

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.FXMLWindow">
```

and errors

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2541)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2516)
    at ProgramDlaMamy/com.Window.start(Window.java:21)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other)

Comment: I've changed code to this
public FXMLWindow() throws MalformedURLException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        URL url = getClass().getResource("test.fxml");

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load(url);

but still I have the same error